# Не могу понять как нормально использовать ForEach в разных случаях

Tags: javascript

Функция getCommonElements(firstArray, secondArray) принимает два массива произвольной длины в параметры firstArray и secondArray, и возвращает новый массив их общих элементов, то есть присутствующих в обоих массивах.

Выполни рефакторинг функции таким образом, чтобы вместо цикла for она использовала метод forEach.

Пробовал так:

```
firstArray.forEach(function(Array) {
     if (secondArray.includes(Array) {
       commonElements.push(Array);
     }   
});
```

```js
function getCommonElements(firstArray, secondArray) {
  const commonElements = [];
  // Change code below this lineтекст, выделенный жирным шрифтом
  for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i += 1) {
    if (secondArray.includes(firstArray[i])) {
      commonElements.push(firstArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return commonElements;
  // Change code above this line***
}
```

Comment: В вашем примере нет forEach. Покажите, что вы пробовали сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: надо for  переделать в forEach

Comment: вот - getCommonElements(firstArray, secondArray) принимает два массива произвольной длины в параметры firstArray и secondArray, и возвращает новый массив их общих элементов, то есть присутствующих в обоих массивах.

Выполни рефакторинг функции таким образом, чтобы вместо цикла for она использовала метод forEach.

Comment: Ну так и в чем именно возникла проблема?

Comment: не могу нормально переписать for в метод forEach , пробовал но не правильно

Comment: Вот и покажите вашу попытку сделать это. Я могу дать готовый вариант, но тогда вы ничему не научитесь... Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него свои попытки решения

Comment: первый раз тут, еще разбираюсь как правильно код тут постить

Comment: Я вам его отформатировал, можете посмотреть, как это выглядит "внутри" вопроса - если кратко, 4 пробела ) По вашему коду, метод forEach принимает 3 параметра - текущий элемент, индекс элемента и сам массив. вы передаете первый, но назвали его не правильно, Array - ключевое слово, не используйте его. Замените на стандартное item и должно сработать

Comment: поменял Array на item но теперь пишет if (secondArray.includes(item) { SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Comment: Забыли закрывающую скобку `if (secondArray.includes(item)) {` <- вот так должно быть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ЗАДАЧА. ОБЩИЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ forEach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489855/) -- неделю назад был точно такой же вопрос

Comment: дааа точно) спасибо огромное!

Comment: @NowhereMan Я до последнего не хотел показывать этот вопрос, что бы человек разобрался в своем коде.

Comment: @SwaD за что и спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: Будут вопросы, заходи еще, только сразу со своими попытками и своими ошибками )